# как в PyQt5 QMainWindow совместить QText... и Buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Как не пытался изобразить текстовое поле с кнопками в 1 окне - не получилось... Кто знает как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit

import sys


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget) 

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Button 2")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


app = QApplication([])

foo = MyMainWindow()
foo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5):

Нужно было создать свой центральный виджет, на нем разместить нужные виджеты, а после тот центральный виджет указать в `setCentralWidget`:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class FormWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button2 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 2")

        self.layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.form_widget = FormWidget(parent)
        self.text_edit = Qt.QTextEdit()

        main_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)

        central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]